# How can i make a subroutine click a picture box?

Tags: vb.net

I have the sub routine for when the picture box is clicked.

```
Public Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click


        If player = "p1" Then
            PictureBox5.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.cross
            pic5 = 1
        End If

        If player = "p2" Then
            PictureBox5.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.nought
            pic5 = 2
        End If
        blnFlag = True
        PictureBox5.Update()
    End Sub
```

I want to create a subroutine that clicks the picture box to change the image to a nought.
Does anyone have any idea on how i would go about doing this.

Comment: That's not how it works. What you do is put the functionality you have there in its own method, then you call that method from the `Click` event handler of the `PictureBox` as well as anywhere else you need to invoke that same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can accomplish this:

1. Call the click event `PictureBox5_Click()` inside a sub:

   ```
   Private Sub AnotherClick_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) handles AnotherClick.Click 
         ~Do Stuff
         PictureBox5_Click(sender, e)
    End Sub
   ```
2. Use `PerformClick()`:

`Me.PictureBox5.PerformClick()`

Edit: I updated option 1 to include the full click event sub. Should add that this is not really an "acceptable" way of writing code, you shouldn't call these event handlers directly, but rather put your logic in another sub/function and call it from there whenever you need. However, if there is some reason you need to specifically call this event handler, option 1 is the way to go.

Comment: what would i put in the sender and e part of the call

Comment: @AadilAhmad You can use `PictureBox5_Click(PictureBox5, EventArgs.Empty)`

Comment: Again, as the comment on the original post mentioned, that's not how you should do it. The way it should be done is to put the code you want to run into its own method. You then call that method from the click event, as well as from anywhere else you want to call it from.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub SetPicture(PicBox as PictureBox)\
  If player = "p1" Then
    PicBox.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.cross
    pic5 = 1
  End If

  If player = "p2" Then
    PickBox.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.nought
    pic5 = 2
  End If
  blnFlag = True
  PicBox.Update()
End Sub

Public Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
  SetPicture(PictureBox5)
End Sub
```

That's how it should be done... now you can also call SetPicture from anywhere else, passing in any other picture box you want...

Comment: @LarsTech Interesting edit but the VS editor uses 4 spaces for indent.